# Copy records between persistent stores in core data?

Tags: ios, core-data

I want to copy data from one store to an other. Destination persistent store could already have records. Is it any easier way, than manually go though all the records and insert into the new context and save?

Comment: The only way I've managed to accomplish this is to  show a progress indicator view after an app launch that locks the view state and then proceed to manually migrate the stores. I've only done this twice when I needed to completely migrate my Core Data models. For incremental changes I would just use automatic migration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to copy **all** of the data, you can use `migratePersistentStore:toURL:options:withType:error:`, which is a method on `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`. This will effectively copy the entire persistent store to a new persistent store file. Some things to be aware of:

- Despite the name, this method has nothing at all to do with model versioning. Both use the word "migrate" but they're different processes.
- You should be sure that you have saved **all** outstanding changes before attempting this.
- After doing this, the store that you're migrating from is removed from the coordinator-- which means that

  - Any existing references to managed objects are now invalid. You should re-fetch them.
  - If you continue using the coordinator, you're using the new store file.

If you don't want to copy **all** of the data, you need to do it "by hand", fetching objects from the old store and creating equivalent objects in the new one.

Comment: If persistent store exist at destination url, will records erased from destination persistent store or retained and new records appended?

Comment: The built-in migrate method is designed to create a new copy of the persistent store, and does not merge with any existing data. Doing it "by hand" works however you write the code.